# There is no suitable CSPRNG installed on your system

Tags: laravel-5

I have a problem with my laravel website while I am hosting it to online server it gets an error says

> There is no suitable CSPRNG installed on your system

I searched the question. But I found nothing that helps me.
Please if someone know how to handle this problem I will be so grateful. Thank you!

The program is coded with laravel 5 and php 7

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I also got surprised by this error after upgrading Symfony. Try this article, the first solution fortunately worked for me:

[How to solve PHP 7.0 Polyfill : There is no suitable CSPRNG installed on your system - paragonie/random_compat](http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/214/how-to-solve-php-7-0-polyfill-there-is-no-suitable-csprng-installed-on-your-system-paragonie-random-compat):

> Although you're not using directly this library, add it to your composer.json as a dependency. Require random_compat with the specific version 1.4:
>
> ```
> {
>     "require": {
>         "paragonie/random_compat": "~1.4"
>     },
> }
> ```
>
> Then run `composer install` (or `composer-update` if you're already using this library) and try to run your project again. If it didn't work try downgrading to 1.3, if it doesn't work neither, then i hope you have the rights to modify PHP settings in your server and go to the next possible solution.

Comment: Or you cand download the downgraded version and upload it to the folder as a hack. :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried these links

- https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat/issues/99
- https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/there-is-no-suitable-csprng-installed-on-your-system
  ?

Seems like you are facing a similar issue.

*Sorry for answering, and not commenting. I don't have enough reputation yet to comment!*

Comment: i checked both links but non of them ware helped me. :(           and finally....